# get merged data from List of object based on properties in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, for-loop

I am using a List , where AccountInformation has three properties

```
public class AccountInformation 
{
        public string AccountNumber{ get; set; }
        public int StartDate { get; set; }
        public int EndDate{ get; set; }
}
```

Now I am getting my List of data something like this

```
AccountNumber  StartDate   EndDate
 AC1           20150101    20150110
 AC1           20150110    20150111
 AC1           20150111    20150112
 AC2           20150112    20150115
 AC1           20150116    20150120
 AC1           20150121    20150125
 AC2           20150125    20150130
 AC2           20150130    20150205
```

Now I need to get this data as final output in below fashion

```
 AccountNumber  StartDate   EndDate
 AC1           20150101    20150111
 AC2           20150112    20150115
 AC1           20150116    20150120
 AC1           20150121    20150125
 AC2           20150125    20150005
```

Means wherever I am getting consecutive AccountNumber as same and EndDate of first row is same as StartDate of next row, I need to merge those rows.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: And *how* do you merge them? What `AccountNumber` and `Start/-EndDate` will the result-entry have?

Comment: This can be done using a simple loop and may be another list to hold the required data. Did you try looping through the list?

Comment: I tried to iterate through for loop and made two list, one which is containing  same AccountNumber and StartDate And EndDate as same and another one which is containing the object having different AccountNumber. After that I had done some manipulation on first list and then merged the first list result to second list...but this solution doesn't seems feasible.

Comment: Btw.: What is your rule for entries that are not consecutive? Should they go to the result as they come or are they also aggregated (which it seems from your desired output). Your question seems pretty unclear to me. Furthermore: allways write what you´ve done as exact as possible to the questions, not into the comments.

Comment: Is it possible, that your `AccountNumber`s are neither consecutive nor equal? For example number `AC1` followed by `AC3`?

Comment: Yes any combination could be possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int outer = 0;

while (outer < accInfo.Count - 1)
{
    if (accInfo[outer].AccountNumber == accInfo[outer + 1].AccountNumber && accInfo[outer].EndDate == accInfo[outer + 1].StartDate)
    {
        if (resultAccInfo.Count == 0)
        {
            resultAccInfo.Add(new AccountInformation()
            {
                AccountNumber = accInfo[outer].AccountNumber,
                StartDate = accInfo[outer].StartDate,
                EndDate = accInfo[outer + 1].EndDate
            });
        }

        else
        {
            resultAccInfo[resultAccInfo.Count - 1].EndDate = accInfo[outer + 1].EndDate;
        }

        outer++;
    }
    else
    {
        resultAccInfo.Add(new AccountInformation()
        {
            AccountNumber = accInfo[outer + 1].AccountNumber,
            StartDate = accInfo[outer + 1].StartDate,
            EndDate = accInfo[outer + 1].EndDate
        });

        outer++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.It is working as per my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Program
{
    public class AccountInformation
    {
        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
        public int StartDate { get; set; }
        public int EndDate { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<AccountInformation> accounts = new List<AccountInformation>();
        accounts.Add(new AccountInformation() { AccountNumber = "AC1", StartDate = 20150101, EndDate = 20150110 });
        accounts.Add(new AccountInformation() { AccountNumber = "AC1", StartDate = 20150110, EndDate = 20150111 });
        accounts.Add(new AccountInformation() { AccountNumber = "AC1", StartDate = 20150111, EndDate = 20150112 });
        accounts.Add(new AccountInformation() { AccountNumber = "AC2", StartDate = 20150112, EndDate = 20150115 });
        accounts.Add(new AccountInformation() { AccountNumber = "AC1", StartDate = 20150116, EndDate = 20150120 });
        accounts.Add(new AccountInformation() { AccountNumber = "AC1", StartDate = 20150121, EndDate = 20150125 });
        accounts.Add(new AccountInformation() { AccountNumber = "AC2", StartDate = 20150125, EndDate = 20150130 });
        accounts.Add(new AccountInformation() { AccountNumber = "AC2", StartDate = 20150130, EndDate = 20150205 });

        List<AccountInformation> newAccounts = new List<AccountInformation>();
        AccountInformation previousAccount = null;
        bool continous = false;
        for (int index=0;index<accounts.Count;index++)
        {

            if (null != previousAccount)
            {
                if (accounts[index].AccountNumber.Equals(previousAccount.AccountNumber) &&
                    accounts[index].StartDate == previousAccount.EndDate)
                {
                    continous = true;
                    if (!(continous && newAccounts.Count>0))
                    {
                        newAccounts.Add(previousAccount);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    continous = false;
                    newAccounts.Add(accounts[index]);
                }
            }
            previousAccount = accounts[index];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is not calculating StartDate and Enddate of same account in correct way.It is always taking StartDate and EndDate of first record